# Problems passing parmaters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, editablegrid

I am trying to pass several variables from a php page into a java script.  However only the first parameter is being passed.

The php page calls the script like this:

```
<?
$sdate = 0;
$edate = 2;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() { 
                datagrid = new DatabaseGrid('<? echo $sdate; ?>', '<? echo $edate; ?>');
            }; 
</script><BR>
```

The Java Script being called is:

```
function DatabaseGrid(sdate, edate) 
{ 
    this.editableGrid = new EditableGrid("demo", {
        enableSort: true,
        tableLoaded: function() { datagrid.initializeGrid(this); },
        modelChanged: function(rowIndex, columnIndex, oldValue, newValue, row) {
            updateCellValue(this, rowIndex, columnIndex, oldValue, newValue, row);
        }
    });
    this.fetchGrid(sdate);
    this.fetchGrid(edate); 

}

DatabaseGrid.prototype.fetchGrid = function(sdate, edate)  {
    // call a PHP script to get the data
    alert("loaddata_dailyotp.php?o=" + sdate + "&e=" + edate + "");
    this.editableGrid.loadXML("loaddata_dailyotp.php?o=" + sdate + "&e=" + edate + "");
};

DatabaseGrid.prototype.initializeGrid = function(grid) {
    grid.renderGrid("tablecontent", "testgrid");
};
```

I added the alert window to show the exactly what was being requested.  I was expecting this:

> loaddata_dailyotp.php?o=0&e=2

However what I am getting is:

> loaddata_dailyotp.php?o=0&e=undefined

Why is my second parameter not going through?

Comment: look how you call fetchGrid, with a single parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing the "edate" parameter to your `fetchGrid()` call. That's why it's displayed as "undefined". For some reason you're calling `fetchGrid()` two times instead.

Answer (score 0):

Call `fetchGrid` like this

```
function DatabaseGrid(sdate, edate) 
{ 
    this.editableGrid = new EditableGrid("demo", {
        enableSort: true,
        tableLoaded: function() { datagrid.initializeGrid(this); },
        modelChanged: function(rowIndex, columnIndex, oldValue, newValue, row) {
            updateCellValue(this, rowIndex, columnIndex, oldValue, newValue, row);
         } 
    });
    this.fetchGrid(sdate, edate);
}
```

You missed to pass the second parameter.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the following way:

```
<script type="application/json">
var payload = <?= json_encode(array('sdate' => $sDate, 'edate' => $eDate)); ?>
</script>
```

and then call your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() { 
   datagrid = new DatabaseGrid(payload.sdate, payload.edate);
}; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharepoint developer. I faced the same issue in one my application where i was passing two values and only first value was reaching the other end. even alert box was showing two values.

Issue was only last values was not reaching other end so CRAZY SOLUTION was to pass 3 parameters, 3rd being test param so my two params were reaching other end and 3rd param which was anyways useless was getting neglected automatically.

Suggestion in your case :

1. Please check with THREE parameters whether you are still getting only 1 param or
2. params ;)